# Why does this piece of C code end up in an infinite loop?

Tags: c, loops, swap, infinite

I have been trying to fix the infinite loop in this code. However, I could not understand why an infinite loop occurs. This code is trying to sort jobs from the smallest to highest before being processed.

```
SortJobs()
{
    linked_list ptr, h, temp, pptr;
    int i, j;

    pptr = ready_queue;
    ptr = ready_queue->next;
    h= ready_queue;

    while(ptr != NULL) {    
        if ((ready_queue->pcb.job_length - ready_queue->pcb.run_time) > (ptr->pcb.job_length - ptr->pcb.run_time)) {
            ready_queue = ptr;
            pptr->next = ptr->next;
            ptr->next = h->next;                
            h->next = pptr->next;
            pptr->next = h;
            ptr=h->next;
            h=ready_queue;
            pptr=ptr->next;
        } else {
            pptr = ptr;
            ptr=ptr->next;          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

`gdb` is your friend for debugging such issues. Please start using debuggers!

OTOH, is this a `circular-(linked)-list`?!

TIP: before running `SortJobs()`, can you run through your `ready_queue` and print all the elements and see whether it goes in an infinite loop?!

The reason for an infinite loop could be because you haven't set the last node in your linked-list to `NULL`. You can check your `addNode()` function.

Comment: stepping through code to see what ptr becomes after each loop is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Because ptr always is not null??

Answer (score 0):

The problem that stands out is that this line:

```
    pptr=ptr->next;
```

can sometimes be followed by this line:

```
    pptr->next = ptr->next;
```

with no changes to `pptr` or `ptr` in between. This will result in a little one-node circular linked list, with `ptr->next->next == ptr->next`. So you can never get out of the linked list.

Overall, I find your algorithm very confusing. You really need to decide on a single logical meaning for each variable, and come up with appropriate loop invariants. For example, at the end of a loop iteration, you'll sometimes have `ptr == pptr->next` (which, I think, is correct), but sometimes `pptr == ptr->next` (which I'm pretty sure is wrong, for the reason given above).

Answer (score 0):

I find your algorithm very confusing and I think it is also wrong. Supposing the loop ends somehow and you did everything right the result you'll get is that the first element is the one with the minimum job_length - run_time, but the rest of the list won't be ordered.

As ruakh pointed out, the problem is that you mess up your list when fiddling with all the next pointer, you're overcomplicating things! I wouldn't touch the structure of the list itself moving entire nodes around, rather use memcpy and move only the data carried by the nodes. Here's a sample funcion:

```
// I assume your linked list is made of nodes such as this
typedef struct {
    struct Node next;
    struct Node prev;     // optional
    struct Somewhat pcb;
} Node;

void swapData(Node *n1, Node *n2)
{
    struct pcb temp;

    memcpy(&temp, n1->pcb, sizeof(struct Somewhat));
    memcpy(n1->pcb, n2->pcb, sizeof(struct Somewhat));
    memcpy(n2->pcb, &temp, sizeof(struct Somewhat));
}
```

Now that we're able to swap correctly nodes, I'd use some well-tested/well-known sorting algorithm, this way you'll find help easier and the next one who will look at your code won't be tempted to kill himself (no offence intended, I'm just kidding ;) ). Let me suggest some simple algorithm such as the [Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) or the [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Not very fast but easy to implement :)